# How can I see and debug a web service response when using a Spring proxy?

Tags: java, web-services, spring, response

I'm writing a Java+Spring client that is calling out to a remote web service. I know that I'm correctly hitting the web service because if I send in a bad id, I receive a custom SOAP Exception from the service saying that there is no student with that id. But if I do send a valid id, the StudentObject returned from the call is null. I have another method used to create a student in their system which returns a string with their new id. Again, I know this works (I've examined the data on the host's system), but my return value is null.

So I would like to be able to examine the response from the web service to know what exactly we're getting back and why it's not mapping into an object correctly. I'd like to see the response written out into a log, but I can't figure out how to get that response. How do I do this?

I defined an Interface to the webservice like this:

```
@WebService(name = "CSM_port", targetNamespace = "wsdl_namespace")
public interface TargetWebService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "getAsObjectBySchoolID", action = "http://blah/getAsObjectBySchoolID")
    @WebResult(name = "student", targetNamespace = "namespace")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "getAsObjectBySchoolID", targetNamespace = "namespace", className = "com.example.IDRequest")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "getAsObjectBySchoolIDResponse", targetNamespace = "namespace", className = "com.example.IDResponse")
    public StudentObject getStudentById(@WebParam(name = "id", targetNamespace = "namespace") String id);
}
```

I'm using a ProxyFactory to create the service (which is then Autowired and injected into my app):

```
<bean id="webService" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="classpath:student_api.wsdl.xml" />
    <property name="namespaceUri" value="namespace" />
    <property name="serviceName" value="CSM_StudentWebService" />
    <property name="portName" value="CSM_StudentWebServicePort" />
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="TargetWebService" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```

Here are relevant chunks from the wsdl:

```
<xsd:complexType name="StudentObject">
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="student_id" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="school_student_id" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="fullname" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="fname" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="mi" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="lname" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="email" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        ... a billion other properties
    </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
<message name="getAsObjectBySchoolIDResponse">
    <part name="student" type="tns:StudentObject"/>
</message>
<operation name="getAsObjectBySchoolID">
    <input message="tns:getAsObjectBySchoolIDRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:getAsObjectBySchoolIDResponse"/>
</operation>
```

And finally, my StudentObject class:

```
public class StudentObject {

    @XmlElement(name="student_id")
    private String symplicityId;
    @XmlElement(name="school_student_id", nillable=true)
    private String schoolId;

    @XmlElement(name="fname", nillable=true)
    private String firstName;
    @XmlElement(name="lname", nillable=true)
    private String lastName;
    @XmlElement(name="email", nillable=true)
    private String email;

    public StudentObject() {
    }
```

}

Comment: While the question dealt more with the debugging problem, the null object was solved eventually solved by adding @SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.RPC) to my service interface. I had completely missed the binding section of the wsdl (it's a big file) where the style was set to "rpc". Adding the SOAPBinding annotation got everything working. Also, I was able to remove the @RequestWrapper and @ResponseWrapper annotations from my methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use tcpmon (http://java.net/projects/tcpmon/) to setup a proxy.  Make it listen on a port and forward it to the server.  All request / response will be logged.

Comment: This approach ended up working better for me than SOAP UI (which is also a really great tool), just because I could see exactly what my app was sending out and receiving.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend leaving Spring out of it for now and trying [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/).  It'll let you easily formulate requests and view all the details of the response when it comes back.